# I want to display my alert this way

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with my application which is [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/testing/Testpage.php). Please follow steps below:

1. When you open the application, click on "Open Grid" and select option 4. Buttons A, B, C and D will appear below.
2. In the Number of Answers textbox, type in the number 1. Then click on 1 button out of A, B, C or D (The button selected will turn green). When you have done that then click on the "Add Question" button twice.
3. As you can see the details you have entered on top will be dispayed in 2 new rows underneath. In the first new row you have added, in the textbox under the "Number of Answers" column, change the number 1 to 0 and in the second row change the number of Answers textbox from 1 to 2. Now click on the "Submit Details" button below.

An alert should appear which states "you have selected less answers than the required amount". and it also states "you have selected more answers than the required amount". This is correct as in the first row, there is one answer selected but in the textbox it states you want 0 number of answers, and in second row there is one answer selected but in textbox it states you wanted 2 answers.

My Question:

What my question is though that except showing both messages in an alert on both rows, what I want is that it will show an alert showing errors in the first row first. After the user has sorted the error in the first row, then if there is an error in second row then when the user clicks on the "Submit Details" button again, then show an alert displaying message of error in second row.

I want the alert to be displayed like this for first row for example:

Please fix error in question 1:
"you have selected less answers than the required amount".

For the alert for the second row I want this:

Please fix error in question 2:
"you have selected more answers than the required amount".

Below is the relevant validation code (I believe the problem is the var context as I think the variable is wrong but I am not sure):

```
  function validation() {

        alertValidation= "";
            // Note, this is just so it's declared...

            $(".numberAnswerTxtRow").each(function() {
  var currenttotal = $(this).closest('.optionAndAnswer').find('.answerBtnsOn') .length;     

            if (!this.value) {
                alertValidation += "\nPlease Enter in the Number of Answers you Require for this question\n";
            }
        else if (currenttotal > $(this).val()){
            alertValidation += "\nYou have selected more answers than the required amount\n";
        }

        else if (currenttotal < $(this).val()) {
            alertValidation += "\nYou have selected less answers than the required amount\n";
        }
        });


        if(alertValidation != "")
        {
            alert(alertValidation);
            return false;
        }
```

Hopefully this makes sense, if it doesn't then please comment to me.

Below is an edit to the validation() function with textarea validation:

```
 function validation() {

$(".textAreaQuestion").each(function() {

   alertValidation= ""; 

        if (!this.value || this.value.length < 5) {
            alertValidation += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question\n";
        }

    if(alertValidation != "") 
    { 
        alert(alertValidation); 
        return false; 
    } 

    });

$(".numberAnswerTxtRow").each(function() { 

    alertValidation= ""; 

    var currenttotal = $(this).closest('.optionAndAnswer').find('.answerBtnsOn') .length;      

    if (!this.value) { 
            alertValidation += "\nPlease Enter in the Number of Answers you Require for this question\n"; 
    } 
    else if (currenttotal > $(this).val()){ 
        alertValidation += "\nYou have selected more answers than the required amount\n"; 
    } 

    else if (currenttotal < $(this).val()) { 
        alertValidation += "\nYou have selected less answers than the required amount\n"; 
    } 

    if(alertValidation != "") 
    { 
        alert(alertValidation); 
        return false; 
    } 
}); 

     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stop the each loop by returning `false` once if any error condition is valid. Try this.

```
  function validation() {

        var alertValidation = "";
        // Note, this is just so it's declared...

        $(".numberAnswerTxtRow").each(function() {
            var currenttotal = $(this)
                               .closest('.optionAndAnswer')
                               .find('.answerBtnsOn').length;     

            if (!this.value) {
                alertValidation += "\nPlease Enter in the Number of Answers you Require for this question\n";
            }
            else if (currenttotal > $(this).val()){
                 alertValidation += "\nYou have selected more answers than the required amount\n";
            }

            else if (currenttotal < $(this).val()) {
                 alertValidation += "\nYou have selected less answers than the required amount\n";
            }
            if(alertValidation != ""){
                return false;//Stop the each loop
            }
        });


        if(alertValidation != "")
        {
            alert(alertValidation);
            return false;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I havn't seen this answer. I have tested this and this seems like a very good solution. Best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your if check within the loop. This should alert and return if the first row finds an error.  If it doesn't, it will continue to check the second row and return there if it finds and error.

```
function validation() {

    $(".numberAnswerTxtRow").each(function() {

        alertValidation= "";

        var currenttotal = $(this).closest('.optionAndAnswer').find('.answerBtnsOn') .length;     

        if (!this.value) {
            alertValidation += "\nPlease Enter in the Number of Answers you Require for this question\n";
        }
        else if (currenttotal > $(this).val()){
            alertValidation += "\nYou have selected more answers than the required amount\n";
        }

        else if (currenttotal < $(this).val()) {
            alertValidation += "\nYou have selected less answers than the required amount\n";
        }

        if(alertValidation != "")
        {
            alert(alertValidation);
            //Ends the loop
            return false;
        }
    });

 //Do other stuff here...
}
```

Comment: If I do it your way, then I just want to know that I am going to add a textarea in the table for each row, if a textarea is empty, then does this : `$(".textAreaQuestion").each(function() {` go on top as well or where will this go?

Comment: This will alert and return out of the each loop back into your main function validation() { }.  Anything else you want to do can be done outside this loop.

Comment: I editted my question to include the new code at the bottom which shows Your answer and the textarea validation as weill, is that code correct if you know? Is this what you meant?

Comment: In the edit code, Lets say in row 1 I leave the textarea empty and I select more answers than required, then when I click on "Submit Details" button, will the alert show both the question is invalid message and you select more answers than required message? If it does then this is what I want

Comment: The way you have it now, if the invalid message alerts it will display that first.  When you close the alert, it will immediately open another alert if there is an error found in the numberAnswerTxtRow loop.

Comment: I have looked at the other answer  and that answer actually works the way I want it, so I gave that answer the best answer but I wil still upvote this answer when I reach reputation of 15. Thanks :)